# Plot address for POI instead of lat and lng mapquest open api

Tags: javascript, api, openstreetmap, mapquest

Currently I convert the address to lat and lng in the backend (php) then plot the point with the code below.

```
var point = new MQA.Poi({ lat: result[i]['Lat'], lng: result[i]['Lng'] });
map.addShape(point);
```

How would I be able to plot the point with just an address rather than converting it myself. The reason I want to do this as I loop through addresses in the backend and get the lat lng for about 90 addresses from a db and it takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

map.geocodeAndAddLocations('Denver CO');

https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/javascript-api/geocoding